# Outlook VSTO - moving my group next to "New Mail" group

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I have made an addin (New Flux Ad Mail) for Outlook and would like to move it's position next to the "New" group - see picture.

[image: OutlookAddin]

Currently, I have this in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
          <group id="fluxAdMail" label="Flux Ad Mail">
              <button id="btnNewFluxMail" label="New Flux Ad Mail" onAction="click" size="large" imageMso="NewMail"/>
          </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I noticed that there's something in the `<group>` section called `insertAfterMso` and I'm wondering if that's what I need to use set the position of my group. However, I have a hard time finding any information regarding this or what the different name/id is for the controls

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right avenue - the `insertAfterMso` attribute specifies the identifier for the built-in control after which to position this control. You can can find the list of built-in control IDs at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers . Use the `GroupMailNew` idMso value for the `insertAfterMso` attribute in case of Explorer windows.

If you only need to find control names, you can discover them within Office applications by hovering over commands in the `Customize Ribbon` tab of the `Options` dialog and looking at the tooltip:

[image: customize ribbon dialog]